# Is there a way to store requests when circuit breaker is open?

Tags: asp.net-core, polly, circuit-breaker

I need to save our requests to process them later when the circuit breaker leaves the fault state and goes back to closed. The only way I found was using rabbit-mq, ​​is there another way using the Polly library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to save our requests to process them later when the circuit breaker leaves the fault state and goes back to closed. The only way I found was using rabbit-mq, ​​is there another way using the Polly library?

Polly is only concerned with handling transient faults during the lifecycle of the original execution.  Polly does not offer mechanisms to store commands persistently for later execution.